# web scraping in r with SelectorGadget

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I was running this simple code below to scrape the employee number from this Fortune 500 page. I used the Chrome's extention: SelectorGadget to identify that the number I want matches with ".info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7"

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
#download google chrome extention: SelectorGadget
link = "https://fortune.com/company/walmart/"
page = read_html(link)
Employees = page %>% html_nodes(".info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7") %>% html_text()
Employees
```

However, it returned "character(0)". Does anyone know what is the cause? I feel it must be a simple mistake somewhere. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Here is the code I modified based on Jon's comments.

```
a <- c("https://fortune.com/company/walmart/", "https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/"              
,"https://fortune.com/company/apple/"                   
,"https://fortune.com/company/cvs-health/"              
,"https://fortune.com/company/unitedhealth-group/"      
, "https://fortune.com/company/berkshire-hathaway/"      
, "https://fortune.com/company/mckesson/"                
,"https://fortune.com/company/amerisourcebergen/"       
, "https://fortune.com/company/alphabet/"                
, "https://fortune.com/company/exxon-mobil/"             
,"https://fortune.com/company/att/"                     
,"https://fortune.com/company/costco/"                  
,"https://fortune.com/company/cigna/"                   
, "https://fortune.com/company/cardinal-health/"         
,"https://fortune.com/company/microsoft/"               
,"https://fortune.com/company/walgreens-boots-alliance/"
,"https://fortune.com/company/kroger/"                  
, "https://fortune.com/company/home-depot/"              
,"https://fortune.com/company/jpmorgan-chase/"          
,"https://fortune.com/company/verizon/"                 
,"https://fortune.com/company/ford-motor/"              
, "https://fortune.com/company/general-motors/"          
,"https://fortune.com/company/anthem/"                  
, "https://fortune.com/company/centene/"                 
,"https://fortune.com/company/fannie-mae/"              
, "https://fortune.com/company/comcast/"                 
, "https://fortune.com/company/chevron/"                 
,"https://fortune.com/company/dell-technologies/"       
,"https://fortune.com/company/bank-of-america-corp/"    
,"https://fortune.com/company/target/")


find_by_name <- function(list_data, name, elem = NULL) {
  idx <- which(sapply(list_data, \(x) x$name) == name, arr.ind = TRUE)
  stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
  if (length(idx) > 1) { idx <- idx[1] }
  dat <- list_data[[idx]]
  if (is.null(elem)) dat else dat[[elem]]
}

numEmp <- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(a)){
  json_data <- read_html(a[i]) |>
    html_element("script#preload") |> 
    html_text() |>
    sub("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    sub(";\\s*$", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>
    fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)
  
  
  
  temp<-gsub(".*https://fortune.com", "", a[i])
  page_data <- json_data$components$page[[temp]]
  
  info_data <- page_data |> 
    find_by_name("body", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
    find_by_name("company-information", "config")
  
  
  numEmp[i] <- info_data$employees # Results will be fed into this numEmp variable.
}
numEmp
```

An error says

> Error in find_by_name(page_data, "body", "children") :
> length(idx) > 0 is not TRUE

Should I somehow change the code `stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)`?

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to work? It seems that data on fortune.com is dynamically produced/rendered using `JavaScript` (and therefore not present in the html source). I imagine you'd need something like `RSelenium` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do `document.querySelectorAll(".info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7")` I see you want to scrape the # of employees. Maurits is right, looks like the data is downloaded as (inline) JSON and then rendered later. You can use Selenium to save the rendered page then apply your CSS selector there. Or you can extract the inline JSON and scrape it from there.

After some manual work, you can do the 2nd option like below in R 4.2.x

```r
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

# R 4.1.x
sub2 <- function(x, pattern, replacement) sub(pattern, replacement, x = x, perl = TRUE)

url <- "https://fortune.com/company/walmart/"
json_data <- read_html(url) |>
  html_element("script#preload") |> 
  html_text() |>
  ## sub("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |> # R 4.2.x
  sub2("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "") |>                       # R 4.1.x
  ## sub(";\\s*$", "", x = _, perl = TRUE) |>  # R 4.2.x
  sub2(";\\s*$", "") |>                        # R 4.1.x
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE)

page_data <- json_data$components$page[["/company/walmart/"]]

find_by_name <- function(list_data, name, elem = NULL) {
  idx <- which(sapply(list_data, \(x) x$name) == name, arr.ind = TRUE)
  stopifnot(length(idx) > 0)
  if (length(idx) > 1) { idx <- idx[1] }
  dat <- list_data[[idx]]
  if (is.null(elem)) dat else dat[[elem]]
}

info_data <- page_data |> 
  find_by_name("body", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-information", "config")

info_data$employees
#> [1] "2300000"

# Extra code to scrape company-data-table segments
library(purrr)
data_tables <- page_data |>
  find_by_name("body", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-table-wrapper", "children")

rows <- data_tables |>
  lapply(\(x) c(x$config$data, x$config$change)) |>
  purrr::flatten() |>
  discard(~ is.null(.$key))

df <- data.frame(
  key = rows |> map_chr(~ .$key),
  title = rows |> map_chr(~ .$fieldMeta$title),
  type = rows |> map_chr(~ .$fieldMeta$type),
  value = rows |> map_chr(~ .$value)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon for your response and for pointing out two directions! I was trying to run your code above. However, the underscore symbol in "x = _," was marked as an error in my RStudio. And I got the following error message: "Error: unexpected input in:
"  html_text() |>
  sub("\\s*window\\.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ", "", x = _"" Do you have any thought on what is causing the error?

Comment: You're probably using R 4.1.x since `_` placeholder does not work (new in R 4.2.0) while `|>` & `\(x) x$name` work. I recommend you upgrade to 4.2. If you can't, see `sub2` in the revised code. Basically rearrange the args to make it compatible with pipes. If you don't like pipes you can expand it one transformation-at-a-time using intermediate variables.

Comment: Jon, thank you so much for your reply! One more question, I'm really new to this: If I want to scrape other numbers on this same webpage (e.g., Measure Up Rank's "20"), how should I modify the code you drafted above? (I tried but couldn't figure this out ; I really appreciate your help!)

Comment: Jon, sorry I have to scrape almost all the table data. Something I have tried but didn't work:                                    
  ```info_data <- page_data |> 
  find_by_name("body", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-about-wrapper", "children") |>
  find_by_name("company-data-table", "children")|>
  find_by_name("table", "children") |>
  find_by_name("rows", "value")"```

Comment: The `company-data-table` _objects_ have a different structure so `find_by_name` is not applicable. I added extra code to scrape them.

Comment: Jon, you are truly amazing. Thank you so much! Message me if you have a chance to visit Chicago. Hope I can thank you in person!

Comment: I was trying to modify your code for more webpages. However, I encountered an error I believe related to the find_by_name function. It says ** Error in find_by_name(page_data, "body", "children") : 
  length(idx) < 0 is not TRUE ** Could you please take another look? I updated the code above and the data. Thanks in advance again!